# JS files not laoding for Application when using Kubernetes nginx Ingress rules

Tags: reactjs, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to add path based ingress rules for react web application.
If I go to example.com/abc to abc application and example.com/xyz to Xyz application

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /abc(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: abc-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /xyz(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: xyz-service
          servicePort: 80
```

But if I tried path / instead of /abc it works. Not for xyz

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: abc-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /xyz(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: xyz-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: How did you access the application in the second case when `path: /(.*)`? What was the URL that worked. Was it `example.com/` or `example.com/abc/`? Also use [chome devtools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) (or simmilar depending on what browser you are using) to check what is happening with network traffic. Maybe browser is requesting JS files from / and this is why it is not reaching the app. In such case (as you already mentioned in comments) application may require changes from developer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```yaml
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /abc/?(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: abc-service
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /xyz/?(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: xyz-service
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: did not worked.. I think app might require changes from the developer.. btw whats diff bet $1 vs $2 ?

Comment: $n (where n is an number) is a reference to *capturing group* number in regexp matching string.